# proper html for vertical div's and resposive height

Tags: html, css

I want to make header and content area where user can write something. I want make it responsive. This is my html:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='writingTask header'>
    <i title='Save' class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>        
  </div>

  <div class='writingTask content'>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>      
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;  
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url('http://static1.grsites.com/archive/textures/beige/beige001.jpg')
}

.writingTask.header {
  width: 100%;
}

.writingTask.header > i {
  float: right;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin: 5px;  
}


.writingTask.content {
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  clear:both;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  resize: none;
  background-image: url('http://static1.grsites.com/archive/textures/beige/beige001.jpg');

}
```

This is [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jaqoyigiso/edit?html,css,js,output). As you can see, `textarea` is bigger than container. I know that it's because of `height:100%`. How to properly style this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope [this](http://jsbin.com/hudojisiwu/edit?html,css,js,output) is what you want.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;  
  height: 55%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url('http://static1.grsites.com/archive/textures/beige/beige001.jpg');
  display: table;
}

.writingTask.header {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-row;
}

.writingTask.header > i {
  float: right;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin: 5px;  
}


.writingTask.content {
  height:91%;
  overflow:hidden;
  clear:both;
  display: table-row
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  resize: none;
  background-image: url('http://static1.grsites.com/archive/textures/beige/beige001.jpg');

}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='writingTask header'>
    <i title='Save' class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>
    
  </div>
 
  <div class='writingTask content'>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

The **container** is displayed as *table* and the **header & content** are displayed *table-row*. This way the textarea only expands to the remaining size.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code snippet:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;  
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url('http://static1.grsites.com/archive/textures/beige/beige001.jpg')
}

.writingTask.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.writingTask.header > i {
  float: right;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  
}


.writingTask.content {
  height: 80%;
  overflow:hidden;
  clear:both;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  resize: none;
  background-image: url('http://static1.grsites.com/archive/textures/beige/beige001.jpg');

}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='writingTask header'>
    <i title='Save' class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>        
  </div>

  <div class='writingTask content'>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: I think it's not good solution because you use 20% and 80%. On the big resolution header will be very big, that's why I didn't specify `height` for `.header`.